# Mock exception using Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, mocking, pytest

I have the following basic function which requests specific API. This function handles four types of exception(HTTPError, ConnectionError, Timeout and RequestException).

```
import requests


HACKER_NEWS_BASE_URL = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/'
TOP_STORIES_ENDPOINT = 'beststories'
API_SUFFIX = '.json?print=pretty'


def get_top_stories_list():

    try:
        resp = requests.get(f'{HACKER_NEWS_BASE_URL}{TOP_STORIES_ENDPOINT}{API_SUFFIX}')
        return resp.json()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print("Http Error:", errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print("Error Connecting:", errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print("Timeout Error:", errt)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print("OOps: Something Else", err)
```

How can I mock and test the exception that could be raised in conditions that are out of my control using pytest?

I've tried patching with something like this:

```
from top_tech_stories import get_top_stories_list

import pytest
import requests


def test_api():
    with patch('top_tech_stories.get_top_stories_list', side_effect=requests.exceptions.HTTPError):
        assert get_top_stories_list() == None
```

but it seems it didn't mock the exception and the function returns a valid non-empty list.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mocking the wrong name. Your test script uses the global `get_top_stories_list` to call the function, but you are patching the module attribute name.

However, you don't want to mock the function you are calling; you want to mock `top_tech_stories.requests.get`, which is what your function calls to produce the exception.